# Change style of nativebase input field when it is focused

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using nativebase which I ejected into my project and added a custom theme.

Now I want to have all my textinput elements and picker elements use a different borderColor when they are onFocus. Something like this:

```js
 <Item regular 
  onFocus={() => {
   this.setState({ onFocus: true });
  }}
  style={onFocus? { color: theme.onFocusInput} : { color: theme.default}}
   <Input/>
</Item>
```

However this does not work since there is no onFocus property in the `<Item>` component.
Also I don't want to define this in every screen I am using input elements. This should be somewhere defined in my nativebase components (proberly Item.js).

I am not sure if I can just write a custom component which extends `<Item>` and use this instead while still having the correct theming. But this would still not solve the problem that `<Item>` still has no `onFocus` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<Item regular style={{ borderRadius: 10, marginBottom: 10 }}>
   <Input
        onFocus={() => {
           this.setState({ onFocus: true });
        }}
        onBlur={() => {
           this.setState({ onFocus: false});
        }}
        style={{ color: this.state.onFocus ? theme.onFocusInput : theme.default}}
    />
</Item>
```

or you can simply `create method` that sets the `backgroundColor` when the `input` if `focus` or `blur` and use it in `style`. Like

```
const focused = () => {
  this.setState({ backgroundcolor: "" })
}

const blured = () => {
 this.setState({ backgroundcolor: "" })
}

 <Item regular style={{ borderRadius: 10, marginBottom: 10 }}>
    <Input
       onFocus={this.focused}
       onBlur={this.blured}
       style={{ color: this.state.backgroundcolor }}
     />
 </Item>
```

Comment: your second approach is better than the one I postet but I will still have to add this in every screen. I would like to have this somehow defined in the Input.js (or wherever) of the nativebase theme. Another problem is that I actually need to change the style of the parent  ``<Item>``  which does not have a onFocus Property

Comment: could you create snack for this so it will be easy to debug the problem you are facing.

Comment: I changed my question to make it more clear. Hope that helps.

Comment: that's default from nativebase . I did not modify it at all. ``<Item>`` is a nativebase component.

Comment: could you provide link for `Item Component` i don't see it in documentation.

Comment: me neither, so I pasted it here: https://hastebin.com/fadebedule.js

Comment: Sorry without snack it is harder to debug.

Comment: sorry I cannot share my complete project

Comment: you need not share complete project just create some screen with random values that is helpful.

Comment: well I created an expo project with nativebase and replicated the sample it but I have no idea how to get this into snack since there are tons of dependencies...

Comment: you can just go to `snack` and `paste` the `code` and it will show the `packages` to `import` and `share` the `link`

Comment: Well thats what I was trying todo and I get tons of error. "Unable to resolve module native base..."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200933/discussion-between-zlzimon-and-kamal-pandey).

Comment: Your solution is functional. I believe that this is the cleanest way to approach it for gluestack